# mongodb - need to process massive data, with only one server instance

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to process about a hundred million records in mongodb. Basically, each key (prescription number) responds to about 1300 records (not unique). These keys have been **indexed.**

Right now, I am querying specific key with pymongo to return those sets of results so they can be processed with python.

Querying mongo is the biggest bottle neck.  It is taking about **20 seconds per query**.  At the current rate, it will take **400 hrs** to query every record.

*This is what I looks like when I 'explain' my query:*

```
db.prescriptions.find({'key':68565299}).explain()

                            {
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "nscanned" : 103578563,
    "nscannedObjects" : 103578563,
    "n" : 1603,
    "millis" : 287665,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "indexBounds" : {

    }
}
```

And this shows that I have the indexes in place

```
> db.prescriptions.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "processed_data.prescriptions",
        "name" : "_id_"
    }
]
```

Am I off my rocker for trying to run this data processing on one server instance?
(Interestingly, my CPU and RAM do not appear to be maxed out when I run top.)

I would be grateful for any advice.

Thanks!!

Comment: Your explain shows a full table scan, no index is used. show the indexes you've created `db.prescriptions.getIndexes()` (add it to the question). Also what does "Basically, each key has about 1300 of its own records" mean - that doesn't in and of itself make sense.

Comment: 1300 records respond to a single key - they are not unique.

Comment: > db.prescriptions.getIndexes()
[
 {
  "v" : 1,
  "key" : {
   "_id" : 1
  },
  "ns" : "processed_data.prescriptions",
  "name" : "_id_"
 }
]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Add an index

From the explain result in the query, there is no index on "key", you need to add one.

```
> db.prescriptions.addIndex({'key': 1});
```

If mongo reports any kind of warning, you'll need to action it

Comment: Thanks AD7six. I realized that despite running the ensureindex with the python wrapper, that I never received the warning which told me that I was out of disk space.  I'm going to add some more disk space and then try again.  I really appreciate your help :)